# Proper way to do simple single row update in SqlAlchemy 2.x?

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, python-asyncio

I'm in the process of migrating from SQLAlchemy 1.4 to 2.0.  I've got inserts working via this function:

```
async def db_insert(engine, table_name: str, values={}):

    from sqlalchemy import Table, MetaData

    try:
        async with engine.begin() as conn:
            table = await conn.run_sync(lambda conn: Table(table_name, MetaData(), autoload_with=conn))
            statement = table.insert().values(values)
            result = await conn.execute(statement)
            return result

    except Exception as e:
        raise e
```

Example code calling the function:

```
async def main():

    from sqlalchemy.ext.asyncio import create_async_engine

    try:
        engine = create_async_engine()
        values = {'col_a': "value1", 'col_b': "value2",  'col_c': 123}
        result = await db_insert(engine, "mytable", values)
        await engine.dispose()
    except Exception as e:
        quit(e)
```

Now the question: how do I update one of those existing rows, for example change 'col_c' to 456?  I'd assume [update()](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/tutorial/data_update.html) but having some trouble understanding what the syntax should be, and how to specify which row to update without hard-coding column names.

Database is MySQL 5 and Framework is Starlette 0.25.0.  Python 3.11.2

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand the question/problem.  The syntax update is pretty similar to insert with an additional `where()` clause that specifies what rows to update.  If it was just a single row then you could identify it in the where clause and its primary key you could get back from an insert.

Comment: Can you provide an Example?